# MS SQL - total CPU time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Could anyone help me in which table within SQL SERVER I can find information about Total CPU time? Or upload a script through which I find out it.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Total CPU for the SQL Server process? A query? The server?

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2454/how-to-find-out-how-much-cpu-a-sql-server-process-is-really-using/ can give the answer of your question

Comment: gbn, the server

Comment: You could put `SET STATISTICS TIME ON;` at the top of your query before executing it. Then look on the Messages tab of the results pane. Here is a link for further reading, [Click Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-statistics-time-transact-sql)